# PreparedStatement uncategorized sqlTimeOut exception at the time of inserting data in to table

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

Inserting data in to table in loop based on list size using preparedStatement. 
Application throwing SQLTimeoutException in Oracle

```
Nested exception is java.lang.SQLTimeOutException : ORA-01013
```

Comment: Inserting only 5 columns and client did not cancel the query. Insertion is happening inside the loop.

Comment: I don't mean your code cancels the request. AFAIK, JDBC driver can do it automatically.

Comment: How we can resolve the exception

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01013` is an exception raised when an operation is cancelled by the client. In your case, I think, the problem could be in timeout settings. Query works too long and JDBC requests a cancel.

Comment: Query is not cancelled by client. Exception is occurring at live